# Do I need a custom iterator for a std::vector<custom>?

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

The following code is getting a compilation error:

```
const D_Value_BufRef_Vec& values = records.at(record_type);

// return begin/end zip iterators for traversing field:value list.
return std::make_pair(
          boost::make_zip_iterator(  
                       boost::make_tuple(fields.begin(), 
                                 values.begin())
                       ),
          boost::make_zip_iterator(
                       boost::make_tuple(fields.end(), 
                                 values.end())
                       )
          );    // <-- Line 752
```

**fields** is `std::vector<string>`.  **values** is `std::vector<MemRef>`.  Previously, **values** was `std::vector<string>` and it compiled fine.  `MemRef` is a custom class replacing `string`.

The error is:

```
In file included from /usr/include/boost/tuple/tuple.hpp:33,
                 from /mxhome/charrison/git/sdcore/libs/CommUtils/include/Block.h:20,
                 from ./c/Block.cpp:1:
/usr/include/boost/tuple/detail/tuple_basic.hpp: In constructor 'boost::tuples::cons<HT, boost::tuples::null_type>::cons(const boost::tuples::cons<HT2, boost::tuples::null_type>&) [with HT2 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const MemRef*, std::vector<MemRef, std::allocator<MemRef> > >, HT = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*, std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >]':
/usr/include/boost/tuple/detail/tuple_basic.hpp:373:   instantiated from 'boost::tuples::cons<HT, TT>::cons(const boost::tuples::cons<HT2, TT2>&) [with HT2 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*, std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, TT2 = boost::tuples::cons<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const MemRef*, std::vector<MemRef, std::allocator<MemRef> > >, boost::tuples::null_type>, HT = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*, std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, TT = boost::tuples::cons<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*, std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, boost::tuples::null_type>]'
/usr/include/boost/tuple/detail/tuple_basic.hpp:635:   instantiated from 'boost::tuples::tuple<T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9>::tuple(const boost::tuples::cons<HT2, TT2>&) [with U1 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*, std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, U2 = boost::tuples::cons<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const MemRef*, std::vector<MemRef, std::allocator<MemRef> > >, boost::tuples::null_type>, T0 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*, std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, T1 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*, std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, T2 = boost::tuples::null_type, T3 = boost::tuples::null_type, T4 = boost::tuples::null_type, T5 = boost::tuples::null_type, T6 = boost::tuples::null_type, T7 = boost::tuples::null_type, T8 = boost::tuples::null_type, T9 = boost::tuples::null_type]'
/usr/include/boost/iterator/zip_iterator.hpp:488:   instantiated from 'boost::zip_iterator<IteratorTuple>::zip_iterator(const boost::zip_iterator<OtherIteratorTuple>&, typename boost::enable_if_convertible<OtherIterator, Iterator>::type*) [with OtherIteratorTuple = boost::tuples::tuple<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*, std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const MemRef*, std::vector<MemRef, std::allocator<MemRef> > >, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type>, IteratorTuple = boost::tuples::tuple<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*, std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*, std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type>]'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_pair.h:107:   instantiated from 'std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(std::pair<_U1, _U2>&&) [with _U1 = boost::zip_iterator<boost::tuples::tuple<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*, std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const MemRef*, std::vector<MemRef, std::allocator<MemRef> > >, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type> >, _U2 = boost::zip_iterator<boost::tuples::tuple<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*, std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const MemRef*, std::vector<MemRef, std::allocator<MemRef> > >, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type> >, _T1 = boost::zip_iterator<boost::tuples::tuple<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*, std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*, std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type> >, _T2 = boost::zip_iterator<boost::tuples::tuple<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*, std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*, std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type> >]'
./c/Block.cpp:752:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/boost/tuple/detail/tuple_basic.hpp:451: error: no matching function for call to '__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*, std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >::__normal_iterator(const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const MemRef*, std::vector<MemRef, std::allocator<MemRef> > >&)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_iterator.h:686: note: candidates are: __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::__normal_iterator(const _Iterator&) [with _Iterator = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*, _Container = std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_iterator.h:683: note:                 __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::__normal_iterator() [with _Iterator = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*, _Container = std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_iterator.h:669: note:                 __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*, std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >::__normal_iterator(const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*, std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >&)
```

From occasional appearances of the word "iterator" I'm wondering whether the compiler doesn't know how to deal with `values.begin()` or `.end()`.  If this is the problem, I don't understand why computing `std::vector<string>.end()` would be any different from computing `std::vector<MemRef>.end()`.  If an iterator is an abstract pointer, required only to be dereferenceable and incrementable, how much does it need to know about the specific thing that's stored in the `std::vector`?

On the other hand, there may be more to that error message than I'm seeing :-/

**UPDATE 1:** at@MikeSeymour's suggestion I found that the enclosing function was declared to return a

```
std::pair< boost::zip_iterator< 
    boost::tuple< 
        std::vector<string>::iterator, 
        std::vector<string>::iterator >  // should be vector<MemRef> !!
    > ,
    boost::tuple< 
        std::vector<string>::iterator, 
        std::vector<string>::iterator >  // should be vector<MemRef> !! 
    > 
>
```

After correcting to vector as noted, I still get an error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/boost/tuple/tuple.hpp:33,
                 from /mxhome/charrison/git/sdcore/libs/CommUtils/include/Block.h:20,
                 from ./c/Block.cpp:1:
/usr/include/boost/tuple/detail/tuple_basic.hpp: In constructor 'boost::tuples::cons<HT, boost::tuples::null_type>::cons(const boost::tuples::cons<HT2, boost::tuples::null_type>&) [with HT2 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const MemRef*, std::vector<MemRef, std::allocator<MemRef> > >, HT = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<MemRef*, std::vector<MemRef, std::allocator<MemRef> > >]':
/usr/include/boost/tuple/detail/tuple_basic.hpp:373:   instantiated from 'boost::tuples::cons<HT, TT>::cons(const boost::tuples::cons<HT2, TT2>&) [with HT2 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*, std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, TT2 = boost::tuples::cons<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const MemRef*, std::vector<MemRef, std::allocator<MemRef> > >, boost::tuples::null_type>, HT = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*, std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, TT = boost::tuples::cons<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<MemRef*, std::vector<MemRef, std::allocator<MemRef> > >, boost::tuples::null_type>]'
/usr/include/boost/tuple/detail/tuple_basic.hpp:635:   instantiated from 'boost::tuples::tuple<T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9>::tuple(const boost::tuples::cons<HT2, TT2>&) [with U1 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*, std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, U2 = boost::tuples::cons<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const MemRef*, std::vector<MemRef, std::allocator<MemRef> > >, boost::tuples::null_type>, T0 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*, std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, T1 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<MemRef*, std::vector<MemRef, std::allocator<MemRef> > >, T2 = boost::tuples::null_type, T3 = boost::tuples::null_type, T4 = boost::tuples::null_type, T5 = boost::tuples::null_type, T6 = boost::tuples::null_type, T7 = boost::tuples::null_type, T8 = boost::tuples::null_type, T9 = boost::tuples::null_type]'
/usr/include/boost/iterator/zip_iterator.hpp:488:   instantiated from 'boost::zip_iterator<IteratorTuple>::zip_iterator(const boost::zip_iterator<OtherIteratorTuple>&, typename boost::enable_if_convertible<OtherIterator, Iterator>::type*) [with OtherIteratorTuple = boost::tuples::tuple<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*, std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const MemRef*, std::vector<MemRef, std::allocator<MemRef> > >, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type>, IteratorTuple = boost::tuples::tuple<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*, std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<MemRef*, std::vector<MemRef, std::allocator<MemRef> > >, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type>]'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_pair.h:107:   instantiated from 'std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(std::pair<_U1, _U2>&&) [with _U1 = boost::zip_iterator<boost::tuples::tuple<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*, std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const MemRef*, std::vector<MemRef, std::allocator<MemRef> > >, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type> >, _U2 = boost::zip_iterator<boost::tuples::tuple<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*, std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const MemRef*, std::vector<MemRef, std::allocator<MemRef> > >, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type> >, _T1 = boost::zip_iterator<boost::tuples::tuple<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*, std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<MemRef*, std::vector<MemRef, std::allocator<MemRef> > >, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type> >, _T2 = boost::zip_iterator<boost::tuples::tuple<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*, std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<MemRef*, std::vector<MemRef, std::allocator<MemRef> > >, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type> >]'
./c/Block.cpp:752:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/boost/tuple/detail/tuple_basic.hpp:451: error: no matching function for call to '__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<MemRef*, std::vector<MemRef, std::allocator<MemRef> > >::__normal_iterator(const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const MemRef*, std::vector<MemRef, std::allocator<MemRef> > >&)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_iterator.h:686: note: candidates are: __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::__normal_iterator(const _Iterator&) [with _Iterator = MemRef*, _Container = std::vector<MemRef, std::allocator<MemRef> >]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_iterator.h:683: note:                 __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::__normal_iterator() [with _Iterator = MemRef*, _Container = std::vector<MemRef, std::allocator<MemRef> >]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_iterator.h:669: note:                 __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<MemRef*, std::vector<MemRef, std::allocator<MemRef> > >::__normal_iterator(const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<MemRef*, std::vector<MemRef, std::allocator<MemRef> > >&)
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to initialise a `vector<string>::iterator` from a `vector<MemRef>::iterator`. Check the function's return type - I'm guessing that still mentions `string` when it shouldn't.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: you're correct: the function's return value was still declared to be std::pair< boost::zip_iterator< boost::tuple< std::vector<string>::iterator, *std::vector<string>::iterator* > > ... >.  But after having corrected that to *std::vector<MemRef>::iterator* , I am still getting a "similar-looking" error.

Comment: I'll try and put some followup into the question so that it has a prayer of being readable.

Comment: It appears that your return type is a non-const `iterator` that you are trying to initialize from a `const_iterator`.

Comment: @Casey, @MikeSeymour, I'm not supposed to say thank you, but thank you.  There was actually quite a bit of constness that I had to change, and I'm not sure why merely changing `string` to `MemRef` had such far-reaching effects, but it now compiles.  And clearly, I was on the wrong track with the subject line of my original question.